# IIS7 https on localhost Using Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: https, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64

I have a win 7 x64 box I recently reimaged and I have installed IIS7.5 and PHP 7. I am trying to set up localhost sites for secure https and I have successfully created a self-signed certificate for this purpose. I have set the IIS bindings for the site to use https over port 443 (IP Address: All unassigned) and selected the new SS cert.

When I go to https://localhost/php_info.php on my computer, I can see the phpInfo content but Chrome displays alerts that site is not secure.

Certificate error: There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).

Obsolete connection settings: The connection to this site uses a strong protocol (TLS 1.2), a strong key exchange (ECDHE_RSA with P-256), and an obsolete cipher (AES_256_CBC with HMAC-SHA1).

What can I do to run secure sites over localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate error can be fixed if you generate another certificate, with Subject Alternative Name (which is required by Chrome). More information can be found in,

https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0

The TLS cipher should be cleaned up by using a tool such as IIS Crypt,

https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto

Jexus Manager has SSL Diagnostics, which can provide you hints on what's wrong in your server configuration,

https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Thank you Lex Li for the answer!